# Photo gallery css selected state not read by cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cookies

I have a Photo gallery where people can select photo's. If they select a photo a class will be added, selected. I set a cookie, so on page reload it would show the photo's they selected and not selected. The cookie gets set, but it would not read it. Meaning none will be selected if I reload the page.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ele cat_collection" data-category="collection">
   <div class="thumbnail paper-shadow">
      <div class="hover-menu-container">
         <div class="hover-menu">
            <ul>
               <li><a class="btn-cmd btn-concrete selectThis" href="#"><i class="fi fi-check"></i></a></li>
               <li><a class="btn-cmd btn-concrete read-this" href="#" data-target=".R1"><i class="fi fi-pencil-cap"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="thumb-image"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var body_class = $.cookie('selected');
   if(body_class) {
       $(this).closest('.ele').attr('class', body_class);
   }

  $('.selectThis').on('click', function () {
       var container = $(this).closest('.ele');
       container.toggleClass('selected');
       $.cookie('selected', $(this).closest('.ele').attr('class'), { expires: 365, path: '/'});
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `if(body_class) { $(this) ...` in your case, you're referring to `document`. You should refer to the element containing photo which have been clicked.

**Note**: storing single `selected` value in cookie will not let you check which element has been selected. You should store an list (array) of selected elements and identify each of them by an attribute (either by `id` or `data`). **Identification attribute have to be unique for each element**

Add **unique** `data-id` attribute for each `.ele` element:

```
<div class="ele cat_collection" data-id="1" data-category="collection">
    ...
</div>
<div class="ele cat_collection" data-id="2" data-category="collection">
    ...
</div>
...
```

Check if cookie exists. If it does, split its value by comma (as it should contain list of selected elements in form: `1,2,3,...`), or set an empty array if the cookie doesn't exists:

```
var classesArray = $.cookie('selected') ? $.cookie('selected').split(',') : [];
```

Loop through the cookie list and append `selected` class only for these `.ele` elements, whose the `data-id` attribute have been stored in the cookie:

```
$.each(classesArray, function(k, v) {
    $('.ele[data-id="'+v+'"]').addClass('selected');  
});
```

Set on `.selectThis` click event. Toggle element class, make a new selected items list (array) and store it in the cookie:

```
$('.selectThis').on('click', function () {
    // toggle class:
    $(this).closest('.ele').toggleClass('selected');
    // make a new list of selected elements:
    classesArray = [];
    $('.ele.selected').each(function(){
        classesArray.push($(this).data('id'));
    });
    // store the new list of selected elements in the cookie:
    $.cookie("selected", classesArray.join(','), { expires: 365, path: '/'});
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/philip100/wuf5fpjm/)**

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the great writing, really clear. Now I understand what I did wrong.

Comment: @Gfive , glad I could help. So it could be accepted as a solution? :-)

Comment: Yep, and just did that.